# Too many sprites produces on this action

Tags: andengine

This is my sprite class and i want to call the method on tapping the sprite and there should also b a time delay. The onGenerate() method is in activity class

```
public boolean onAreaTouched(TouchEvent pSceneTouchEvent,
        float pTouchAreaLocalX, float pTouchAreaLocalY) {
    if(pSceneTouchEvent.getAction()==TouchEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
        this.clearEntityModifiers();
        this.setVisible(false);
        this.clearUpdateHandlers();
        this.reset();
        myActivity.onGenerate();
    }
```

Comment: so what exactly is your problem??

Comment: i want to create some delay in attaching the sprites and after attaching second time the should behave in different way

Comment: use a Timerhandler to create a delay

Comment: how Timehandler is called again and again